# page layout not displaying as expected when using position:fixed for page content

Tags: mmenu

I'm having an issue with position:fixed regarding my mmenu's show/hide anchor (in this case, a hamburger icon).

Selecting the icon toggles the menu as expected, but with the menu open, the page is pushed down ~32px from the top in Safari, Chrome and Firefox in OS X, as well as Safari iOS 8. Surprisingly, the page displays correctly in IE 10 and 11.

I've added:

```
<script src="js/jquery.mmenu.fixedelements.js"></script>
```

to the page, and assigned the class "FixedTop" to the div containing the anchor. All 100% heights are marked up as 100vh.

I've also tried wrapping the entire page in a `div#wrapper` and adding`"Selector: '#wrapper'"` when firing the plugin to override the default `"body > div"`. I've since removed the `div#wrapper`.

Below are two links - one for a `position:fixed` example, and the other for a `position:static` example.

The only difference between the two is "layout.css" in the fixed example includes a `position:fixed` style for the div containing the anchor.

http://www.alibimedia.com/mm-fixed

http://www.alibimedia.com/mm-static

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Fred at mmenu offered this solution:

Add a `padding-top` (for example of 1px) to the `<DIV class="content">`, this way the `margin-top` from the `<H1>` stays inside it.

Works like a charm! Thanks Fred.

Answer (score 0):

this confused me for a moment as the OP talks about removing the #wraper div.  But I added it to my wrapper (as recommended in the docs to wrap your content in a single div) and it works like a charm.

Posted incase it confuses anyone else.